# cannot get 'wget --recursive' to work

Tags: https, wget

I would like to download this page:

```
https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/ms-a0210/viikkoharjoitukset
```

as well as its subpages, especially the .pdf documents:

```
https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/ms-a0210/viikkoharjoitukset/MS-A0210_thursday_30_oct.pdf
https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/ms-a0210/viikkoharjoitukset/MS-A0210_hints_for_w45.pdf
etc.
```

When I give this command:

```
$ wget --page-requisites --convert-links --recursive --level=0 --no-check-certificate --no-proxy -E -H -Dnoppa.aalto.fi -k https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/ms-a0210/viikkoharjoitukset
```

I get:

```
$ ls -R
.:
noppa.aalto.fi

./noppa.aalto.fi:
noppa  robots.txt

./noppa.aalto.fi/noppa:
kurssi

./noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi:
ms-a0210

./noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/ms-a0210:
viikkoharjoitukset.html
```

I have tried several wget options, with no luck.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Site doesn't work at all? It's loading forever. Anyway, judging your output, it seems it does recursively follow links... Maybe it's just taking long or you're getting timeouts.

Comment: The site works: my browser (Chrome) loads https://noppa.aalto.fi/noppa/kurssi/ms-a0210/viikkoharjoitukset without delays, and the wget command I gave completes in 0.4 seconds. No timeouts whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `wget` adheres to `robots.txt` files, which, in this case, disallows all access:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
```

If you add `-e robots=off` to your command line, `wget` will not care for a `robots.txt` file.